# Como faço para pegar registros de meu banco de dados em ordem crescente(de id), porém quero que ele pegue um por um

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aplicação-web

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if($conn){
        $Selectdb = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'quiz');
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta LIMIT 1";
    $execsql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Erro");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execsql)){
        # code...
        $IdPergunta = $row['id_pergunta'];
        $p = $row['pergunta'];
        $ra = $row['respostaa'];
        $rb = $row['respostab'];
        $rc = $row['respostac'];
        $rd = $row['respostad'];
        $vp = $row['valor_pergunta'];


    }
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
    echo '<root>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="IdPergunta">' . $IdPergunta . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="ValorPergunta">' . $vp . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="Pergunta">' . $p . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaA">' . $ra . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaB">' . $rb . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaC">' . $rc . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaD">' . $rd . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '</root>';


?>
```

Comment: Não tem sentido você pegar um por um de seu banco de dados. Pegue a quantidade máxima de registros desejada e vá percorrendo os registros recuperados de um em um  em sua aplicação PHP. A cláusula ORDER BY será útil para você.

Comment: Já tentei colocar `"SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta DESC"` mas só fica na primeira pergunta.

Comment: Você quer dizer que no seu banco existem vários registros mas seu script PHP só mostra um? Talvez porque a exibição está sendo feita fora do loop?

Comment: então o select tem que está dentro do while? Mas se eu deixar dentro do lopp o mysqli_query fica incompleto.

Comment: Não, dentro de seu loop você simplesmente vai atribuindo o que recuperou do banco mas sṕo sai do loop e exibe a última.

Comment: Não entendi a logística, poderia ser mais claro e detalhado, sou novo me programação.

Answer (score 0):

Logo após a "id_pergunta" na instrução $sql na quarta linha, remova o "LIMIT 1" e adicione o ordenador ASC, para que seus dados venham do banco em ordem crescente. Antes:`$sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta LIMIT 1";` Depois `$sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta ASC";`. Isso resolve um dos seus problemas.

Comment: Obrigado, porem não sei como fazer a segunda parte

Comment: Poderia informar quais campos você possui no seu banco de dados, para que eu possa recriar a situação e analisa-la?

Comment: Tem os seguintes campos: id_pergunta, peprgunta, respostaa, respostab, respostac, respostad,resposta_correta,  valor_questão.(exatamente nesta ordem)

Answer (score 0):

Remova o "LIMIT 1" do comando SQL
Ficaria assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta";
```

Você pode, se quiser, adicionar o "ASC" no comando, que seria para consultar em ordem crescente, ficando assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta ASC";
```

*Mas não considero o ASC necessário, já que ele consulta em ordem crescente por padrão.*